# javascript type is function

Tags: javascript

how to work with only one type of javascript do? so

```
is ({}) // object
is (function () {}) // function
```

running towards me is() I need function. **not jQuery** thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so; Here's how:

```
Type = {

    isrgx: /\[|\]|object| /g,

    toString: function(args) {

        return (Object.prototype.toString.call(args));
    },

    is: function(args) {

        return (this.toString((args || "")).replace(this.isrgx, ""));
    }
};
```

**Type.is()**

```
Type.is({}); // --> Object

Type.is(function() {}); // --> function

Type.is("dklsk"); // --> String

Type.is(111); // --> Number
```

would be better if we add the following :) **isFunction (), isObject ()**

```
Type = {

    isrgx: /\[|\]|object| /g,

    toString: function(val) {

        return (Object.prototype.toString.call(val));
    },

    is: function(val) {

        return (this.toString((val || "")).replace(this.isrgx, ""));
    },


    isFunction: function(val) {

        return (this.is(val) == "Function");
    },

    isObject: function(val) {

        return (this.is(val) == "Object");
    }
};
```

**Type.isObject()**

```
Type.isObject({}); // --> true
Type.isObject("dsds"); //--> false
```

**Type.isFunction()**

```
Type.isFunction(function() {}); // --> true
type.isFunction("dsdsds"); // --> false
```

take it easy...

Answer (score 3):

Use the `typeof` operator.

```
var type = typeof(function() {}); // "function"
type = typeof({}) // "object"
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't entirely imagine what you are saying but if you want to check the 'type' of a particular function you can do

```
if (typeof(myFunc) === 'function')
```